# My CSS is not getting injected through my content script

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Can anyone explain this to me. I'm trying to inject a CSS file onto a webpage using the content_script with Google extensions, but my css file never gets added to the webpage. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me fix it? thanks

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "0",
  "description": "",


  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*"],
        "css": ["myStyles.css"],
        "js": ["myScript.js"],
        "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

myStyles.css

```
#test {
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The style sheet is actually injected, but not applied, because other styles override the rules. To get the rules to work, you have some options:

1. Increase the [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) of your CSS rules.
2. Suffix every rule with `!important`:

   ```
   #test {
       margin: 0 10px !important;
       background: #fff !important;
       padding: 3px !important;
       color: #000 !important;
   }
   ```
3. Inject the CSS via a content script:

   `myScript.js`:

   ```
   var style = document.createElement('link');
   style.rel = 'stylesheet';
   style.type = 'text/css';
   style.href = chrome.extension.getURL('myStyles.css');
   (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(style);
   ```

   `manifest.json`

   ```
   {
     "name": "Extension",
     "version": "0",
     "description": "",
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*"],
     "content_scripts": [
       {
           "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*"],
           "js": ["myScript.js"],
           "all_frames": true
       }
     ],
     "web_accessible_resources": ["myStyles.css"]
   }
   ```

   The last key, `web_accessible_resources` is necessary when [manifest version](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html) 2 is active, so that the CSS file can be read from a non-extension page.

Comment: For clarification: You do **not** have to use both methods. Using one of them will be fine. The first one is more reliable, the second one *may* cause a flicker.

Comment: #1 works for me but #2 not working. It's really weird. Is it possible that the original page trying to block the extension to change its style? On some websites (eg, appannie.com) it's ok but some are not (eg, facebook.com). Anyway, #1 is great. Thanks!

Comment: @Xan It becomes the last stylesheet in the document, so if the specificity is at least as high as the existing stylesheets in the document, then the injected stylesheet takes precedence.

Comment: @RobW, that's dubious. How to prevent the webmaster from loading another stylesheet right after yours is injected?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target a specific website do:

`"matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"]`

That `//*` before `.google` is the real trick for me as using `www` doesn't works.