# How to change a webpage's css with Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My CSS is not getting injected through my content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script)

I wanted to make an extension which can insert another css ( http://users.atw.hu/zoleest/gportal2.css) to a webpage ( http://seriaya.gportal.hu/*) automatically, I read articles about it for hours, tried everything, but they have never working. Can anyone help me with a source or a sample extension for it?

Comment: check out the StyleBot extension.

Comment: @GrahamClark is StyeBot open source?

Comment: @Whymarrh I don't know. But if it already does what's required, it might be an alternative to building something else.

Comment: See also [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), and note that you can easily unpack Chrome (and Firefox) extensions to see the source inside.