# Cannot change style of HTML elements using jQuery by content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm writing an extension for chrome as "Content script". My extension should change the background color of google home page (https://www.google.com)
I wrote this code (including jquery):

```
$(".gsib_a").style="background:#FF0000";
```

But not worked. I'm sure I added jQuery to content script, and the manifest.json file is set. I am sure because this code works:

```
$(".gsib_a").hide();
```

And I am sure changing **style** of the element with class of **gsib_a** is exactly what I need and affects. Because I've tested it by **Chrome Developer Tools**.

Okay, who knows the problem?

Comment: Do you want to change styles only? If yes, why not just inject CSS instead of JavaScript? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script) for sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change an attribute, use the [attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):
​
`$('.gsib_a').attr('style','background-color:#FF0000')​;`

but you can change the css directly with the [css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
​$('.gsib_a').css('background-color','#FF0000')​;
```

Comment: Yes, the first code worked. But the second one does not work. However, thank you.

Comment: the difference: the first code resets the style, the second just changes or sets the background-color. Maybe there is a background-image, which hides the background-color or something like that.