# Chrome Extension CSS manipulation

Tags: css, google-chrome, scripting, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My CSS is not getting injected through my content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script)

I've been trying to make a Chrome Extension to change the background color of google to black every time it's loaded in a tab.

I have the following in my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Background to black",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Google black",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://www.google.com/*"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["backgroundtoblack.css"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

and this in my backgroundtoblack.css:

```
body{
background: #000000;
}
```

However it doesn't work for me and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just a side-note: there are already extensions that do that and more (like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)).

Comment: Well I'm interested in learning how to do it myself. But thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: "background color of google" — did you mean [google.com](http://google.com) page?

Comment: This **might** be about the fact that Chrome might utilize HTTPS by default, so your rule `"http://www.google.com/*"` won't match it. Can you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't about the manifest file, it's about your CSS file. Replacing your CSS with this,

```
html, body {
    background: #000000 !important;
}
```

The extension should work now. (Works when testing locally).

**Note:** I had to change your `matches` a bit, because I use HTTPS Everywhere. You might have to change it if Chrome is loading using HTTPS by default.

Comment: Changing the css alone made it work, thanks. Is it the !important that makes the difference or the html, body; or is it a combination of both?