# Why this matche not working just for css file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My CSS is not getting injected through my content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script)

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "TESTE",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Description",
    "content_scripts": [
        {       
            "matches": ["http://*/*wss"],// <<---------
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "js":["alert.js"]
        }       
    ],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>","http://*/*"]
}
```

The js file is working perfectly, but the css just load if i put generic match like

```
"matches":["http://*/*"]
```

Why?

Comment: WHat site do you want to match?

Comment: Anyone with suffix "wss"...
like
"http://www.anyone.com/service.wss"

Comment: @But is there anything else after i? A query string/URL fragment. Eg ...service.wss?foo=bar

Comment: No, in real the page is exactly like this one "www.anyone.com/service?wss"...
Always I have the suffix "wss" or "?wss"...

But, the real point is... why this match(["http://*/*wss"]) work to js files but not for css files??

Comment: Thanks Rob W for clarification and I think you are right, this questions is same question but when I searched I not found. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68561) that exists for over an year now.

Temporary solution for this is to inject CSS from content script javascript:

```
var link=document.createElement("link");
link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
link.setAttribute("href", chrome.extension.getURL("main.css"));

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```