# Injecting CSS through google chrome content script. Manifest.json fails, but succeeds with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting some JavaScript and CSS into a YouTube page. [The documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) seems to indicate that this should be possible. Am I doing anything incorrectly? Is this is a YouTube thing? Or is injection broken in content scripts?

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/watch?v*"],
      "css": ["ChromeExtension/css/inject.css"],
      "js": ["Shared/js/thirdParty/jquery.js", "ChromeExtension/js/inject.js"]
    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "ChromeExtension/css/inject.css",
    "ChromeExtension/icon.png"
  ]
```

Here's my relevant manifest.json.

Now, when I just have inject.css requested through my content_script, I do not even see a request on youtube.com. However, if I define my CSS file as a web_accessible_resource, then I can load my CSS through my javascript like so:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href =  chrome.extension.getURL('ChromeExtension/css/inject.css');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.documentElement.insertBefore(link);
```

Any obvious reason why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My CSS is not getting injected through my content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script)

Answer (score -1):

Try avoiding relative paths in content scripts, put all JS and CSS code in root path and try

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/watch?v*"],
      "css": ["inject.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "inject.js"]
    }
]
```

If you have many files and do not want to disturb folder structure you can use programmatic injection on load:

Ex:

```
onload = function (){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "path"});
}
```