# Chrome Plugin Development

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to get started with Chrome Plugin Development.

After googling i found a few websites to get started.

We are basically looking to develop a plugin for Gmail. On loading Gmail it should start a bar like how SmartR plugin does to the right right of the Gmail Layout as shown below

[image]

Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: Seems like simple HTML/CSS Injection to me. And Google has a whole site for chrome extensions. I think you missed that.

Comment: @Bibhas thanks i will check the site. yeah it is html/css injection. but any idea how to make sure it is injected to the side the whole browser?

Comment: Just the way you design a HTML page. There is no magic there. You reduce the width of the whole content and fit your content in the extra space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has built a whole site dedicated to Chrome Extension Development: [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html).

Answer (score 2):

Doing what you are sought out to do is really simple. You have to just write a .css, .js and inject it on only gmail.com domain (manifest.json). Due to chrome's isolated world policy, there won't be any problems between your JS code in the content script and the code on the webpage.

However, you have to isolate your CSS rules from webpage's CSS rules otherwise you might end up screwing webpage's content or your own content. A starting point for that would be:
[My CSS is not getting injected through my content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script/9721569#9721569)