# Chrome extension: CSS file won't get injected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that uses a CSS file, but it just does not get injected. The manifest file is pretty straight forward

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Youtube Embed Performance",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["https://redcursor.net/channels/18181"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches" : ["https://redcursor.net/channels/18181"],
      "css"     : ["youtube.css"],
      "js"      : ["youtube.js"],
      "run_at"  : "document_start"
    }
  ]

}
```

The script appears in the Sources tab as part of my extension (and gets executed). The CSS won't appear there.

Comment: Have you verified that the script *really* isn't getting injected? Original styles on the page will take precedence over extension styles; by default, only styles not specified on the page can be affected by extension styles. See [My CSS is not getting injected through my content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script) for possible solutions, including increasing selector specificity and using `!important`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, it's there. It didn't appear in the sources tab though, which left me wondering.