# linking css file to chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I have found a few versions of my same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721344/my-css-is-not-getting-injected-through-my-content-script) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553600/how-to-inject-css-using-content-script-file-in-chrome-extension), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804476/adding-css-file-to-chrome-extension-manifest-not-working/35805462#35805462) but when I try the suggested solutions I am still unsuccessful

I notice I am only able to apply inline css rules in my current extension. When I try bringing those rules into a separate css file I can't get the rules linked to the elements on the page.
I have played around mostly with the manifest.json file assuming my problem is somewhere there.  I have tried including only css, matches, and js lines of the content_scripts. I have played around with different permissions. I didn't originally have the web accessible resources section.

Here is my manifest.json file as it currently looks:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "food project",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "My cool extension.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": ["./content.css"],
      "matches": ["https://www.target.com/*", "file:///*/*"],
      "js": ["./content.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "*://*/*"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Demo extension",
    "default_icon": "/images/logo.png",
    "default_badge": "Media Rep"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["./content.css"]
```

and in my content.js file:

```
function addButtonElement() {
  
  const newButton = document.createElement("button");
  
  newButton.textContent = "Click me";
  newButton.className = "buttonn";

  newButton.style.background = "blue"
  newButton.style.position = "relative";
  newButton.style.top = "12.5em";
  newButton.style.left = "50em";
  newButton.style.zIndex = 8000;
  newButton.style.color = "white";
  newButton.style.width = "10%";
  newButton.style.height = "30%";
  newButton.style.borderRadius = "20px";
  newButton.style.padding = "0.5em";
  newButton.style.boxSizing = "border-box";



  const currentButton = document.getElementById("headerMain");
  document.body.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", newButton, currentButton);

}



document.body.onload = addButtonElement;
```

content.css file:

```
.buttonn {
  border: solid 4px red !important;
}
```

I have other functionality in with the js file that is working, and like I said, inline css works. Not really sure why I can't seem to get rules from my CSS file to apply from that file.

one page I am trying this on is
https://www.target.com/p/general-mills-cheerios-honey-nut-breakfast-cereal-19-5oz/-/A-14765766#lnk=sametab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! (kind of)
I think there was maybe a caching issue on my machine...? I had been working on this late into the night yesterday and added in the `!important` command as one of my last steps to be sure my inline rules weren't taking precedence over the CSS.

When I came back to this project in the evening today it all worked!
The power of walking away did it again.
I am new at posting here, so not sure if best practice is to delete the question entirely, but I am tempted to leave it to remind others in the future that taking a break is sometimes the answer :)

Some of the lines added into my manifest.json file above weren't necessary to use my .css file

This is the version I have now that it is working as hoped:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "food project",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "My cool extension.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": ["./content.css"],
      "matches": ["https://www.target.com/*"],
      "js": ["./content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Demo extention",
    "default_icon": "/images/logo.png",
    "default_badge": "Media Rep"
  }
}
```